# SQL: Query where column = x, when column2 != y; y = column when column2 = x..if that makes sense

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table:

```
PK | FK1 | FK2
1  | 1   | 2
2  | 1   | 3
3  | 1   | 6
4  | 2   | 1
5  | 2   | 6
6  | 5   | 3
```

PK is the primary key (dur). FK1 and FK2 are foreign keys to the same column in some other table (not relavent).

## Query type 1

I want to get all rows where FK1 = x. At the same time though, I don't want to include rows where FK2 = y; y is FK1 where FK2 = x. Another way of saying this: FK1 = x, but FK2 cannot equal any value of FK1 in the table where FK2 = x. For example, x = 1:

```
PK | FK1 | FK2 | Returned in Result Set (Yes = √, No = x)
1  | 1   | 2   | x
2  | 1   | 3   | √
3  | 1   | 6   | √
4  | 2   | 1   | x
5  | 2   | 6   | x
6  | 5   | 3   | x
```

Notice, rows where PK >= 4 are not included in the result set because FK1 != 1. However, row where PK = 1 is not included in the result set, yet FK1 = 1. Why? Because FK2 = 2, which is what FK1 equals when FK2 = x or 1 at the row where PK = 4. Read that a few times if you have trouble.

## Query type 2

It's almost like the first type of query. I want to get all rows where FK2 = x and FK1 != y, where y = FK2 where FK1 = x. It's the same, only the columns are reversed. My focus is on FK2, not FK1.

## Query type 3

I want to get all rows where FK1 = x, only if FK2 = y; y = FK1 where FK2 = x. Hopefully you've been following the convention here with x and y, so I won't need to explain much. Here's an example, x = 1:

```
PK | FK1 | FK2 | Returned in Result Set (Yes = √, No = x)
1  | 1   | 2   | √
2  | 1   | 3   | x
3  | 1   | 6   | x
4  | 2   | 1   | x
5  | 2   | 6   | x
6  | 5   | 3   | x
```

Only the first row is returned, PK = 1. Why? Because FK1 = x or 1, and FK2 = y or 2, which is FK1 where FK2 = 1 (row 4).

Man, I hope this makes sense. Tell me where I start to not make sense, and I'll edit.

Thanks for reading. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all of the 3 are fairly simple joins;

The first left join finds all rows with FK1=1, and filters away all rows that have a matching pair with FK1 and FK2 reversed;

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.FK1=t2.FK2 
 AND t1.FK2=t2.FK1
WHERE t2.PK IS NULL
AND t1.FK1 = 1;
```

The second is just the reverse of the same query, finding FK2=1 instead.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.FK1=t2.FK2 
 AND t1.FK2=t2.FK1
WHERE t2.PK IS NULL
AND t1.FK2 = 1;
```

The third is just a straight forward join, no specials.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.FK2=t2.FK1
 AND t1.FK1=t2.FK2
WHERE t1.FK1 = 1;
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61573/4).

Comment: I added more rows, and everything seems to be correct, except that in the last query you forgot t1.FK1 = 1. Right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0317/1

Comment: @Sam Yes, you're probably right, I had some trouble understanding the last description. Updated the answer :)

Comment: @Sam: Don't you have the courtesy to vote for an answer you are using? Did you groww up in a barn or what?